# Angular project deployed on IIS cannot authenticate from outside

Tags: angular, google-compute-engine

Recently, I am working with `angularx-social-login` to login google. It works fine locally, but when I deploy my angular project on `IIS` of an instance of Google Compute Engine (Window Server 12) I see a problem. As long as I stay in my host and login, it still works. However, when I try to login in from other computers, it returns 400 error. Am I wrong at any stages or Google Cloud Engine's instance actually blocks some kinds of requests that I send from my computer. I have searched everywhere and I also set `Authorised JavaScript origins` but it does not fix my problem. Can anyone help me with this ? Thanks

This is the method of Angular that I'm using

```
signInWithGoogle(): void {
    this.authService.signIn(GoogleLoginProvider.PROVIDER_ID)
      .then((x) => {
        console.log('loggedIn', x);
        this.user = x;
        this.sendToRestApiMethod(this.user.idToken);
      }).catch((x) => {
        console.log('error', x);
    });
  }
```

**Bonus**

I spot something, when I click on login button when I am in the host, the redirect URL will be `https://accounts.google.com/signin/oauth`

But when I try to login from other machine and click on the same login button, it returns `https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2`

**BONUS 2**:
I have found something 
It is because of the `angular` login. Generally, if I type the domain name, it will redirect to the IP address of the host. But when the action of Angular is called, it actually sends the `oauth` request based on the host's IP address, not domain name. If I change the IP of the host inside `etc/host` to domain name, it works fine (because it authenticates by the real name not public IP address)

Full detailed result:

[This is the return of google](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3EIF7.png)

Comment: Normally you have to add allowed domains in you app configuration in the google console. Check if you have added your production domain there

Comment: I updated the question. I think it's because of the Angular authentication does require actual domain name, not public IP address. When I call the domain name, it redirects to host's IP address, and Angular actually authenticates by this IP, not domain name. That is the problem but idk how to cope with this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After days of frustration, I have found the solution. This is because I've set my domain each time gets called it redirects to host's ip address. So `Angular` automatically reads the public `ip address` instead of your domain name when calling authentication (when you call the above event), and it does not allow you to do that of course (google login email does require real domain name not public ip address). To fix this I just need to get the domain name servers of the `Google Cloud` instance and then customise them where I created the domain name